# Differences between codeacademy interpreter and Ubuntu's interpreter

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, methods

I'm doing the introduction to Ruby course at CodeAcademy. I've trying to work on my code offline, on my Ubuntu machine. I downloaded the interpreter and I'm using the gedit to write the code, but I'm having some problems. Some programs don't work on Ubuntu. There are methods that my interpreter don't recognize. I've tried online interpreters, but they don't work too. I'll give an example. The following code is one of the programs written during the course.

```
puts "Give me a string."
text = gets
puts "Give me a word to hide."
hide = gets
word = gets.split(" ")
word.each do |word|
   if word != hide
     print word + " "
   else
     print "hided "
   end
end
```

It works perfectly on Codeacademy environment, but when I try to run on Ubuntu, it crashes or stop during the execution. I'm having problems to use methods like .chomp, .split, .reverse..... Almost all methods don't work. Why that happen? Do I have to download some library or something like it's done in the C language? I appreciate the help!

Comment: (1) How do you run your script on the terminal?  Please edit your post to add the full transcript by copy&pasting.  (2) The Ruby interpreter should show a stack trace on raising a severe error.  Please include the stack trace in the above transcript.

Comment: also, could you include the output of `ruby -v`?

Comment: you are using `word` as a the variable holding the array then using word as the name of the variable the block would yield back to each, I think you need to change `word = gets.split(" ")` to `words = gets.split(" ")` and also change `word.each` to `words.each`, though I don't seem to understand the logic behind the piece of code

Comment: 1 - I run by typing "ruby [name of my file].rb"
2 - I don't get any stack trace when I run the program. It just stops. when the program ask "Give me a word to hide", a type the word and press enter but nothing happen.
3 - Here is the output of the verbose:

italo@PCM1:~/Ruby Code$ ruby -v hide.rb
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
Give me a string.
testing the program
Give me a word to hide.
the

That's it. After I give the input, the program stops and I have to type Crtl + C or enter again.

Comment: 4 - Sorry for the way that I posted the code. I still don't know how to format properly the text on these windows.
5 - I made the changes that you suggested on the code, but nothing happened. The program still behaves like before.

Comment: 6 - The program is supposed to do the following.
A - Ask the user for a random phrase.
B - Ask the user for a random word.
C - Split the phrase into words.
D - Compare the words of the phrase with the word that the user typed.
E - Replace the the word that the user typed with "hided" if there is any in the phrase.
For instance: Input: Testing the program /
              Input: the /
              Output: Testing hided program